# How do i .removeClass('active') for just one of my <li> elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues figure out how i can just remove a class ="active" from a just one of my lists.

I have a navigation bar:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also have a menu within Home:

```
<div class="container_2">
  <ul>
    <li class="left-main-list active"><a href="#">Subject 1</a></li>
      <ul class="list-in-list">
        <li><a href="#">Sub subject 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub subject 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="left-main-list><a href="#">Subject 2</a></li>
    <li class="left-main-list><a href="#">Subject 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

While i browse my menu on the home page, i want to change the the active list items class to active when clicked, so i now have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('li').click(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });

 });
```

This works for my menu, the class change to the current one, but it also delete my navigation bars class, which i don't want. :)

I have tried something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.left-main-list').click(function() {
       $('.left-main-list li').removeClass('active'); 
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });

});
```

I've tried '.left-main-list li' & 'li.left-main-list' without any success.

Greatful for answer to this question, and i hope my question (this time) is more accurate than my previous ones. :)

/Bill

ps: Can a sub subject AND a main subject be active at the same time, and that sub subject's class of active, be removed if you for example click another sub subject, but the main item still have it's class of active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While i browse my menu on the home page, i want to change the the
>   active list items class to active when clicked

You could just target the `li`s within the relevant `div`, similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $listItems = $('div.container_2 li');

    $listItems.click(function() {
        $listItems.removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
 });
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AYna5/) - target `li`s within `.container_2` only

---

> Can a sub subject AND a main subject be active at the same time, and
>   that sub subject's class of active, be removed if you for example
>   click another sub subject, but the main item still have it's class of
>   active?

Still targeting the container you could use jQuery's [**parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.container_2 li').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $children = $this.parent().find('li');

        $children.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEHd4/) - Using `parent()` to allow active menu and sub-menu but not when main menu changes

---

I looked at the possibility of making this more dynamic to add activation of items going up the chain when switching between sub menus located within different main menu elements.

Fixing the HTML of the nested `ul`s whereby your nested `ul`s are inside `li`s instead of just inside the upper `ul` you can do a fully dynamic implementation.

Assume your HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container_2">
    <ul>
        <li class="left-main-list active"><a href="#">Subject 1</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="list-in-list">
                <li><a href="#">Sub subject 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub subject 2</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="list-in-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub subject 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub subject 2</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Subject 2</a>

        </li>
        <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Subject 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, using the following script, you can also make parents of any sub menu items active when changing from a sub menu to another which is within another main menu item, similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.container_2 li>a').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $relatedElements = $this.parents('ul').find('li');

        if($this.hasClass('active')){
            return;
        }

        $relatedElements.removeClass('active');
        $this.parent('li').addClass('active');

        var $parents = $this.parents('li');

        $parents.each(function(){
            $(this).not($this.parent()).prev().addClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7dY7/) - Chain-like activation

---

I think this should have all possible examples to get you started from here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @htmlNewbie: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your reply. This was what i needed to know! :) In your latest example however, using siblings(), if you open subject 1 and sub subject 1, they are both activated, but if you leave to subject 2 now, sub subject 1 is still active. =/

Comment: @htmlNewbie: I edited the last DEMO and also added a new example showing a possible example of a chain-activation. I think the answer should now contain plenty of examples to get you started. Hope this helps.

Comment: This was really helpful and all my questions have been answered, thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this.parentNode).children("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

This will affect only the siblings of the element you click on.

Comment: I like this solution very much. It almost does exactly what i would like! :) One thing/problem: If i click on subject 1, and a sub subject, and then move on to next item in the list, subject 2, the sub subject of subject 1 is still active. See: http://jsfiddle.net/czGLK/4/ Probably an easy fix? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.left-main-list').click(function() {   
   $('.left-main-list').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li').click(function() {
    $('li.left-main-list').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`$('li').on ('click', function (){
        $(this).addClass ('active').siblings ('li').removeClass ('active');
    })`